# disable tensorflow warnings and messages

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, deep-learning, warnings

I am using tensorflow==2.10.0 and have been trying to remove these messages which pop up everytime I run my python script. I don't have a Nvidia GPU.

```
2022-10-26 13:58:46.926429: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-10-26 13:58:47.010141: I tensorflow/core/util/util.cc:169] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2022-10-26 13:58:47.013778: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/vojta/anaconda3/envs/newest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/../../lib64:
2022-10-26 13:58:47.013793: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-10-26 13:58:47.031358: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:2981] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2022-10-26 13:58:47.371213: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/vojta/anaconda3/envs/newest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/../../lib64:
2022-10-26 13:58:47.371255: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/vojta/anaconda3/envs/newest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/../../lib64:
2022-10-26 13:58:47.371259: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
```

I googled and tried all of these and none made any difference

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
tf.get_logger().setLevel('INFO') 
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
```

The only thing that worked almost perfectly is this (inside the terminal)

```
TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2 time python main.py
```

however there was still one message at the beginning

```
2022-10-26 13:58:26.477557: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:2981] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
```

and 2 messages everytime i do model.save()

```
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _jit_compiled_convolution_op while saving (showing 3 of 3). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _jit_compiled_convolution_op while saving (showing 3 of 3). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
```

and I would like to be able to solve without having to write extra stuff everytime i want to run my script.

Any ideas on how to get rid of the messages? And why does `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2` work in the terminal but not over `os.environ`?

Thanks for any help

Comment: if you don't have GPU then maybe you should install version for CPU, or you should compile own version from source code. You could also check precompiled versions on https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels/issues

Comment: did you use `os.environ` before importing `tensorflow`?

Comment: i used os.environ after I imported tensorflow

Comment: you could try to use `os.environ` before you import `tensorflow` because it may get value from `os.environ` during import.

Comment: tried and did not work

Comment: I can't help more. I use version specially precompiled without `AVX2` (because I have very old CPU) and I don't get these messages. Besides, for some messages I wouldn't waste time to hide them. For other messages I would rather try resolve problem instead of hide messages.